# Problem with execution after update download

Tags: java

```
public void init() {
    String download = getParameter("update");
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String saveTo = home.concat("\\update.exe");
    download(download, saveTo);
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(saveTo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void download(String url, String path) {
    try {
        URL link = new URL(url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(link.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
        rbc.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The updates are downloaded but I'm not exactly sure if they're being installed.  When I run the updater it downloads the file fine but execution I don't see any prompt of successfully updated or failed to update.  Is there something I need to add to the save location of the update? `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(saveTo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uncommenting your exception handlers, then see what exception you are getting.